# calling an external library function by string

Tags: javascript

In my js code there is a loop which loads a module depending on it's name. Each module returns  HTML code. All it sums up to the website layout. For example a extremely simple module:

```
box = "<div class=\"entity_box\">";
box += "third player address: <span class=\"result\">...</span>";
box += "<button onclick=\"this.parentElement.getElementsByClassName('result')[0].innerHTML=library.returnAddress(thirdPlayer).call()\">call</button>";
box += "</div>";
```

The library contains hundreds of functions, for example:

```
library.returnAddress(player).call()
library.getUser(order).call()
library.getUserLevel(order).call()
library.getPrivilege(sender).call()

library.setPrivilege(player, value).call()
library.addUser(data).call()

and so on
```

I can call all functions manually as I showed above and it works. But the problem is that doing this I would need to write 200 cases of calls in my script for each library function.

I decided that I could make an input text box and let user to call function, so he would be able to write "getUserLevel(25)" and click a button, and gets a result.

Here is what I wrote and it's not working:

```
box = "<div class=\"entity_box\">";
box += "<input type=\"text\" class=\"inputData\" />";
box += "return val: <span class=\"result\">...</span>";
box += "<button onclick=\"library." + $(box).find('.inputData').text() + ".call()\">send</button>";
box += "</div>";
```

Also not working:

```
box = "<div class=\"entity_box\">";
box += "<input type=\"text\" class=\"inputData\" />";
box += "return val: <span class=\"result\">...</span>";
box += "<button onclick=\"let library = new Library(); library.($(box).find('.inputData').text()).call()\">send</button>";
box += "</div>";
```

How can I call function by string where string is set in input?

Trying to do it on https://playcode.io/ but still not working:

[what I was trying to reach but it throws error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcIGg.png)

Example (not working) code:

```
function Library()
{
}

Library.prototype.returnAddress = function(playerId)
{
  return 2525;
}

Library.prototype.otherTest = function(playerId)
{
  return 3333;
}

  let library = new Library();
  box = "<div class=\"entity_box\">";
  box += "Call function by name:";
  box += "<br />";
  box += "<input type=\"text\" class=\"functionName\" />";
  box += "<br />";
    box += "return data: <span class=\"result\">...</span>";
  box += "<br />";
    box += "<button onclick=\"let text = this.parentElement.getElementsByClassName('functionName')[0].value; this.parentElement.getElementsByClassName('result')[0].innerHTML=library.(text)\">call</button>";
    box += "</div>";

$('#msg').html(box)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use eval()

```js
function Library()
{
}

Library.prototype.returnAddress = function(playerId)
{
  return 2525;
}

Library.prototype.otherTest = function(playerId)
{
  return 3333;
}

  let library = new Library();
  box = "<div class=\"entity_box\">";
  box += "Call function by name:";
  box += "<br />";
  box += "<input type=\"text\" class=\"functionName\" />";
  box += "<br />";
    box += "return data: <span class=\"result\">...</span>";
  box += "<br />";
    box += "<button onclick=\"execute(this);\">call</button>";
    box += "</div>";

$('#msg').html(box);

function execute(elm){
  let text = elm.parentElement.getElementsByClassName('functionName')[0].value;
  eval("elm.parentElement.getElementsByClassName('result')[0].innerHTML=library."+text+";");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="msg"></div>
```